# Authentication using .htaccess Fails

Tags: .htaccess

Below htaccess makes it through to the last line but does not redirect to the index.html login form when no cookie present.

Tried numerous variations and most return

I have been stumbling around on this for hours and need some expert direction. Tried numerous variations. Some crash some produce mesages such as "...public_html/.htaccess:90:  was not closed." Which I assume is looping.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP} on [NC]


#Comment: Referrer HTTP://simba.org  
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER}  ^"http://www.simba.org"/ [NC]

#Comment: Is cookie CGISESSID? Indicating logged in?
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*CGISESSID=([^;]+).*$ [NC]

#Block looping
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]

#If not logged on rewrite to login page and exit [L]
# Good No Crash but no redirect
RewriteRule ^http://simba.org/index.html$ [R]
```

Comment: Got redirect showing up in browser but never loads page with message

Comment: Got redirect working to showing new address in addres bar but page does not load Message: Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete. Got this in FF and Blue Moon after very slow response.IE never responded. FF forum in 2012 said this kind of response a problem Any insight or workaround appreciated